# Office 365 Security

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I have a work based Office 365 account and am looking at working remotely, if I open an Excel file on Office 365 it will open Excel online, however, if I want to work on a more complex spreadsheet I can choose to open the file in the local Excel. How secure is this? If I was working on a file and the power cuts would a copy of that file still be on that PC? Is it safe to use Open in Excel on a public computer?

Comment: is the profile you're hypothetically using public? or just the computer? I would be more concerned with caching my Office 365 credentials on a public profile/machine than I would be about potentially leaving a recoverable draft.

Comment: @mael' Just the computer, so I have a work based Office 365 Pro account.

Comment: It is not safe to enter any credentials or view any confidential data on a public computer. You may assume that they no longer belong only to you.

Comment: @harrymc I agree but I'm also concerned about accessing work related documents at home on my single user machine. I don't want to find that Office 365 is storing files on the PC.

Comment: The file will be copied locally, but I don't know if where, and whether it is ever deleted. Even if deleted, there is a chance that a copy will be found in the Recycle Bin. If remote communication is cut, Excel might keep the local updates for the purpose of recovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an Office 365 document is opened using the "Open in app" option, as opposed to using the "Open in browser" option, the document is downloaded from OneDrive and is only stored in RAM, where it is then accessed by the Office suite.

[image]

- all auto saves are uploaded to OneDrive, which is why the entire version history for a document is visible online
- if there is a power failure, the document is lost from memory and no copy is left on the computer's hard drive as none was ever saved there to begin with
- usually, the only time a copy would be saved locally to disk is if the user explicitly selected the "Save a Copy" option, and specified "This PC" as the target

[image]

However, if there is connectivity problem and Office is unable to save to OneDrive, the Microsoft Office Upload Center will temporarily save a copy on your hard drive, to allow the updated file to be uploaded as soon as a network connection becomes available again.

If you want to prevent your Office 365 files from being saved to disk under any circumstances, you can simply [disable the Microsoft Office Upload Center](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/02/09/how-to-disable-the-microsoft-office-upload-center/).

[image]